# Why does Python interpreter show same memory location for different objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can someone please explain the following output to me?
[image]

Are not x and y different objects in memory?

Comment: Numbers that are within -5 and 256 are representing the same object

Comment: They aren't different objects.  Both names are bound to the same object.

Comment: @TimRoberts In this case, yes, but it would be different for, say, `a = 300` and `b = 300`. They are asking about the reason why this is so.

Comment: This is telling you that they aren't. Also note, thinking about "memory location" is the wrong level of abstraction in Python. Here you have two references to some object, the ID is the same, during their overlapping lifetime, therefore, they are the same object. IOW, `x is y`.

Comment: Essentially, while you might *expect* these two be two different `int` objects, the Python runtime is free optimize immutable built-in objects and not actually create something new, because semantically, it should never make a difference.